# Weak reference to self in block cause sometimes BAD_EXCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks

[image]I've object and it's using delegate block. I'm using ARC.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)createGame
{
    _game = [[MRCircusGame alloc] init];
    _game.mainView = self.view;
    _game.stageObjectsDictionary = [self getStageObjectsDictionary];
    [_game prepareGame];
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *)getStageObjectsDictionary
{
    StrongMan *strongMan = [[StrongMan alloc] initAndCreateImageViewWithFrame:kStrongManIntroFrame inView:self.view];
    strongMan.isTakingTouches = NO;
    strongMan.isVisible = NO;
    [tempDictionary setObject:strongMan forKey:kMRCircusStrongMan];
    return tempDictionary;
}
```

---

```
@interface MRCircusGame
{
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *stageObjectsDictionary;
}
```

---

```
@implementation StrongMan
..
-(void)method
{
  __weak typeof (self) weak_self = self;
  self.animator.didEndAnimating = ^{
            StrongMan *strongRef = weak_self;
            strongRef.isAnimating = NO;
            [strongRef idle];
  };  
}
```

**Some questions:**

If I don't use weak reference to self, Xcode makes some warning about possible retain cycle. But I take a look in Instruments and no memery leak was detected even I use `self.isAnimating = YES;`

If I don't use this strongRef workaround, *sometimes* I got BAD_EXCESS so I think it weak_self was released am I right? Should I use strongRef all the time to prevent my app from crash?

Will strongRef released as this block execution ends?

Comment: It is not possible do get EXEC_BAD_ACCESS from the code you have shown. Yes, if `self` was deallocated before the block firing then `weak_self` will be `nil`, and so will `strongRef`. But you are just calling methods on `strongRef`, and calling methods on `nil` is okay in Objective-C. You must have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Also, the image you show does not match your code. Which is it?

Comment: Shouldn't be the reference inside the block be to weak_self instead to self? (inside the picture)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a strong reference to a weak reference is a common technique to keep self alive while the block is running. At the end of the block strongRef will be released.

Instruments will only show an unreachable object if

- you use a strong reference to self inside the block
- and you don't nil the reference to the block in dealloc
- and you nil the reference to StrongMan

Comment: or I should use just self and don't care about warning?

Comment: There are three ways to break cycles: 1) Scoping: copy the variable so you don't need to reference self. 2) Programmatically: nil the block property that causes the retain cycle. 3) Attributes: use a weak reference. You can't use 1) because you need to set a property of self, but you can use 2 or 3 at your choice. I prefer 3) so I don't have to remember to nil anything later.

Comment: 1) please can you explain?
2) may I nil even I need this block to be executed?
3) use weak reference for what?

Comment: 1) If you need self.age inside your block, you can do NSUInteger x = self.age; in your method to create a copy, so you refer to your stack variable (x) instead to your ivar (self.age). This eliminates the need to use self. You can't do this in your code because you are setting an ivar (isAnimating) 2) No, not needed because you are already using weak references to avoid cycles. 3) Weak references to refer to self, as you did in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar problem before. The main reason for the problem is, the object is deallocated before the animation ends. So when the block is executed, the referenced "self" is not there.

I think there is two solutions to this problem:

1. You override the "dealloc" method, and then you assign nil to self.animator.didEndAnimating. So nothing is executed after the animation.
2. In the block, you can check weather "self" is nil or not, then do what you want.

Comment: 1 would work, 2 I don't get.. but again AFAICS this shouldn't be needed __weak vars are nilled, no?

Comment: 1) I really need to execute the whole block after animation is completed.
2) Maybe it will works but it's not better to work with strong reference to weak_self from the beginning?

Comment: @alexhajdu then in this case the problem is deallocation of the object. How do you keep that object? I think we are talking about a "view" in this case, so if you assign your view to strong variable of a view controller your problem can be solved as far as I understand.

Comment: "The main reason for the problem is, the object is deallocated before the animation ends. So when the block is executed, the referenced "self" is not there." So the reference will be `nil`. Why would that cause the OP's problem?

Comment: @ÖmerFarukGül I updated question. You can now see how am I creating objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you use weak reference and the instance of `StrongMan` is deallocated before the animation stops your app will crash. To prevent the crash you should remove the reference when the object is being deallocated. Using the following code in your `dealloc` method should do it:

```
self.animator.didEndAnimating = nil;
```

Comment: shouldn't be needed AFAICS __weak will be nilled when self goes away, no?

Answer (score -1):

The proper way to do this is to access the instance variables directly:

```
_animator.didEndAnimating = ^{ .... };
```

Comment: animator is property of StrongMan super class

Comment: ther is no problem with animator, but with execution the code inside the block

Comment: @mundi :: how does that matter? *truly curious*